# What happened to UIViewAnimationOptions.fromMask() and what is the new alternative?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, core-animation

For example in:

```
let curve : AnyObject? = info[UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey]

UIView.animateWithDuration(duration, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.fromMask(curve), animations: { self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, kbFrame.height - self.heightView.frame.height, 0.0) }, completion: { (value: Bool) in println() })
```

What can I do instead now that `.fromMask()` is gone?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

Use `UIViewAnimationOptions(rawValue: curve)` instead. Be sure to (in my example) cast curve as `(info[UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] as NSValue) as UInt`